# Does Django's csrf_exempt decorator remove all POST data?

Tags: python, django, post, python-requests, django-csrf

I have a Django view which returns a list of objects, or allows you to create one if you POST...

```
@csrf_exempt
def quantities(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        kwargs = {**request.POST}
        print(request.POST)
        quantity = Quantity.objects.create(**kwargs)
        return JsonResponse({"quantity": f"/quantities/{quantity.id}/"})
    return JsonResponse([], safe=False)
```

If it gets a GET request it returns a list of quantities (code not shown), which works fine, and if it gets a POST request it uses POST data to create a new quantity. (I'm aware DRF does all this for you, but for my first API I wanted to try doing it manually - you just understand it better that way.)

Anyway in my test, I use requests to check this works...

```
response = requests.post(
 self.live_server_url + f"/quantities/", data={
  "name": "Height", "units": "m", "description": "Human Height"
 }
)
```

This doesn't work - it doesn't pass any data. That `print` statement in the view above just prints `<QueryDict: {}>`. For some reason the POST data that I put in the request has gone from the request by the time it passes through all the middleware and gets to the view.

The only thing I can think of is that the `@csrf_exempt` decorator is removing POST data, though I can't imagine why. I've looked at its source code and it doesn't seem to be doing that, but I can't check because removing the decorator means the view just returns a 403 response.

Where is my POST data going?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this code so I pretty much copy-pasted your code to one of my projects and it worked as expected. You can remove all middleware if you suspect that's the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for trying that! In the end it was a problem with my request headers, not the middleware as I suspected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that for some reason the fact that my request had a header `"Content-Type": "application/json"` was making Django not create a POST dictionary from the request body. I have no idea why but removing that header fixed the issue.

Comment: When posting Json data, you must retrieve it on the backend differently... Rather than change the content type on your post (to an inaccurate content type), you get request.body instead of request.POST.

``data = json.loads(request.body)``
``name = data['name']``

Answer (score 2):

@phenicie comment is correct.

When using csrf except, posting Json data, you must retrieve it on the backend differently... Rather than change the content type on your post (to an inaccurate content type), you get request.body instead of request.POST.

```
data = json.loads(request.body) name = data['name']
```